# Правило для IIS rewrite module

Tags: iis

Есть веб-сервер, который работает под управление DDN (Dot Net Nuke). Я хочу к нему подключить CDN, но у меня огромное количество файлов к которым нужно поменять пути.

Как сделать в Rewrite URL module чтобы при обращении по пути к jpg. например http://site.ru/images/1.jpg меня перенаправляло на http://CDN-URL/images/1.jpg и забирало всю информацию по этой ссылке?

Comment: Так не помогает:
<rule name="CDN-01-js" preCondition="CheckHTML" stopProcessing="true">
<match filterByTags="Script" pattern="http(s)?://www.(site.ru)/(.*\.js)" />
<action type="Rewrite" value="http://CDN_URL/{R:0}" />
</rule>

Answer (score 0):

Надо добавить следующее правило в web.config (в секцию `rewrite -> rules`):

```
<rule name="redirect jpg to cdn" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern=".jpg$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://cdn.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```